# How to show a google map without labels or street name in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I an developing an Android app where the map should be clean and no street name or locality name can be shown. And I want to customize the map layout with styles and setting offers at different locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[from this site you can create custom map style](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

> when you get on map ready callback you can set the custom map style
>   like this

```
  @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.style_json));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom style for a map if you want to customize the view of the map.

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.style_json));
```

Check below link for reference.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/hiding-features